# Adding Multiple Trend Lines with Dynamic Color Change in Time Series Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I'm working on a time series data visualization project in Python using Pandas and Matplotlib. I've successfully plotted individual trend lines for multiple categories on the same time series plot using polynomial regression.

However, I'm looking to enhance the visualization by adding multiple trend lines and dynamically changing the color of each trend line based on its direction (upward or downward trend) within the overall time series. For instance, I aim to have the trend lines appear green when trending upwards and red when trending downwards. I don't have a function or algorithm that finds these trends when going up and down.

I've referred to this [How to calculate and plot multiple linear trends for a time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906679/how-to-calculate-and-plot-multiple-linear-trends-for-a-time-series) Stack Overflow post, which provides insights into plotting multiple linear trends for time series data. However, I lack a specific function or algorithm to identify the trend directions as 'upward' or 'downward.'

Here's a snippet of the Python code I'm using:

```
data = {
'Datum': ['2023-01-09', '2023-01-09', '2023-01-16', '2023-01-16', '2023-01-23', '2023-01-23', '2023-01-30', '2023-01-30', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-20', '2023-02-20', '2023-02-27', '2023-02-27', '2023-03-03', '2023-03-03', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-17', '2023-03-17'],
    'Geslacht': ['M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V', 'M', 'V'],
    'Emood_Score': [7.67, 7.49, 6.67, 6.49, 7.23, 7.23, 6.95, 7.12, 8.0, 7.8, 8.3, 8.2, 5.0, 4.8, 5.5, 5.3, 6.2, 6.0, 5.8, 5.7, 6, 6.1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'])
male_data = df[df['Geslacht'] == 'M'].sort_values(by='Datum')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.plot(male_data['Datum'], male_data['Emood_Score'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='blue', label='Mannelijk')
poly_degree = 1  # Graad van de polynoom (lineaire trend in dit voorbeeld)

coeff_male = np.polyfit(male_data.index.values, male_data['Emood_Score'], poly_degree)
trend_line_male = np.polyval(coeff_male, male_data.index.values)

male_trend_direction = 'up' if coeff_male[0] > 0 else 'down'

plt.plot(male_data['Datum'], trend_line_male, linestyle='--', color='green' if male_trend_direction == 'up' else 'red', label=f'Mannelijke trend ({male_trend_direction})')

plt.xlabel('Datum')
plt.ylabel('mood Score')
plt.title('mood Scores per Geslacht met Trendanalyse')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Is there a built-in method or formula within Matplotlib or any Python library that allows the automatic color change of the trend lines based on their direction? If not, could you guide me on how to implement this feature efficiently?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to post my images!